# Cannot return value owned by a function

Tags: rust

I'm confused with something that should be very simple. I have a function that takes user input, splits it into vector by spaces and return ssaid vector:

```
fn get_rotors() -> Vec<&'static str> {
    let mut foo: String = String::new();   # compiler says "foo" is borrowed from here
    println!("Enter a set of 3 Roman numerals separated by spaces.
            \nFor example: I IV VI");
    let mut ids_input: String = String::new();
    match stdin().read_line(&mut ids_input) {
        Ok(n) => foo = n.to_string().clone(),
        Err(_Error) => foo = "".to_string(),
    };
    let rotor_vec: Vec<_> = foo.split(" ").collect();
    return rotor_vec
}
```

In this version I get a compiler error that I can't return a value owned by the function.

I thought that maybe I should try and dereference it:

```
--snip--
    return *rotor_vec
```

But here I get: `expected struct Vec<&'static str> found slice [&str]`.

Ok, says I, I'll try explicitly converting it to vector when returning:

```
--snip--
return *rotor_vec.to_vec()
```

Same result.

I tried using `clone()`, which also didn't work, so I can't seem to return value from function and I have no idea why it is so.

Comment: Note that it is conventional to make `return` into a *statement* by adding `;` after it in this context, or to omit the `return` keyword (in which case `rotor_vec` will be returned anyway. Also, your `String::new()` invocation is redundant and should be removed (by initialising `foo` with the `match` expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function claims to return a vector of string slices that live forever (`&'static str`). But you actually return a vector of string slices that point into the local `foo` variable, which goes out of scope as the function leaves, so those slices would dangle.

What you really want is to return a `Vec<String>`. Which means that after the split, you need to turn each slice into an owned string with `to_owned`.

Comment: So this means that I need to loop through the vector and apply `to_owned()` to each of the elements?

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot. I didn't know about `to_owned()`